# Python incorrect indent for for-loop (Coursera Python Data Structure courses)

Tags: python, for-loop

Why does my code print the empty list?

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "mbox-short.txt"

fh = open(fname)
count = 0
lst = []
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    word = line.split()

    if len(word) < 0:
        countinue
print(word[1])
```

[the text file can be downloaded here](https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues that I found:

1. Be careful with the indent, which results the empty print
2. The space is matter to find the correct begging place, I accidentally missed the space so that produce the duplicated or repeated result.

[image: multiple repeated results]

```
#Assignment 8.5
#file name = mbox-short.txt
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "mbox-short.txt"

fh = open(fname)
count = 0

for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith('From '): #To check if the line staty with 'From '
            continue    #Note that there is a space behind the From, otherwise the print resuly would duplicated
    word = line.split()
    count = count + 1
    print(word[1]) #be careful with the indent

print("There were", count, "lines in the file with From as the first word")
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)